# Angular 5 listener or directive for button disabled property change

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives

I would like to create kind of directive(?) or listener for buttons. The idea is when the button is disabled, it will move and focus to the next button. I would like to have a loop to moving between not all elements but only buttons which i will define.

```
       <button id="btn1" #button1 [disabled]="checkIfIsDisable()" nextActivekBtn>
        Ändern
      </button>
      <button #button2 type="button"  [disabled]="checkIfIsDisable()">
        Text1
       </button>
      <button #button3 type="button"  [disabled]="checkIfIsDisable()">
        Text1
       </button>
      <button #button4 type="button"  [disabled]="checkIfIsDisable()">
        Text1
       </button>
      <button #button5 type="button"  [disabled]="checkIfIsDisable()">
        Text1
       </button>
```

My idea was to have directive (like `nextActiveBtn`) which will be listening to button property (disabled) and then invoke parent component function which will decide on which button or element to focus. Also i wonder if i can use ViewChildren on these buttons? Let's assume that i have many button in html but I want have subset of them (have only these 5 buttons). I set disabled property in function but I really love to have directive or something independent from this function.

Thanks for any advice or new idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive was not a good alternative for that. Better solution was to create function in component which manage current focus button. Also I add `#navigableButton` to each button and create list contains each of them.

> @ViewChildren('navigateButton') navigableButtons:QueryList `<ElementRef>`;

Thanks to these I could easily find next active button in loop and move to it. Function for managing current button's focus is invoked after function which disabled button.